# Is there any way to kill all ash creatures for good?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

After defeating Dagoth Ur there are still Ash Beasts and Corprus Victims around that will respawn some days after their dead. Is there a way to ultimately "free" them? Maybe a mod if not natively?

Comment: For the record, Ascended Sleepers are one of only a few creatures that have Grand souls - so you probably don't want to get rid of them.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Good point, though I prefer Golden Saints for that, since there's even a spell to conjure them indefinitely :)

Comment: Assuming you have the Conjuration skill or enough scrolls.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar True, but unless you speed-ran that _should_ be the case after defeating Dagoth Ur

Comment: Not necessarily. I pretty much ignored magic. I paid for all my enchantments, but I did need to provide souls.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Oh right, I forgot you can e.g. play a Barbarian with Enchanting skills yet neglect Conjuration entirely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know you cannot ultimately free them in the original game or its official expansions. They will still spawn even after defeating Dagoth Ur. I dont know of any mods which would handle this issue.

For more info you might want to check out this great FAQ: http://faqs.ign.com/articles/497/497229p1.html